# Encoded page downloaded with wget?

Tags: wget

[image]

I'm trying to mirror a site using :

```
wget --header 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8' --header 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' --header 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36' --header 'dnt: 1' --header 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' --header 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' --header 'cookie: _ga=GA1.2.3865356.1523153047; ........'  -N -m -p -w 3 --convert-links  'mysite.com/
```

I've added a couple of headers and noticed that the recursive downloading was not happening. Just the initial index.html page is downloaded. When I looked at the page I see the screenshot. What is being downloaded here. How can I download regular html files instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you add the option  `--server-response` what do you see in the `Content-Type` header of the response? Is it anything like `text/html`?

P.S.: since you used the `-m` (i.e. `--mirror`) option you do not need to specify the flag `-N` as well.